# Repeating an input

Tags: python, input, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and have been working through some tutorials to try to get to grips with different aspects of programming.

I'm stuck on an exercise that is most likely very simple however I am unable to find the solution.

How do I create a program that reads one line of input and prints out the same line two times?

For example if the input was `Echo` it would print:

```
Echo
Echo
```

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated. I think I'm making a simple logic error but don't yet have the skills in place to recognise what it is.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers seem logical enough, but what if you wanted to print it let's say a 1000 times or a million times? Are you really going to be typing print(variable) a million types? Here is a faster way:

```
                               j=input("Enter anything.")
                               for i in range(2):
                                print(j)
```

Here, I can change the value of range to whatever I want, and J will be printed that many times.

What happens here, is that the variable i loops upwards (an increment) to the number 2, so to explain it to a beginner, i travels t=from number to number. Where I put print(j) for every number i loops through until it gets to 2, J will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've been doing the input and output in one go:

```
print(input())
```

That works for doing a single echo of the input, but makes it a bit harder to repeat the same thing twice. An easy workaround would be to save the inputted text to a variable, which you can print twice:

```
text = input()
print(text)
print(text)
```

If you needed to do the input and doubled output with a single statement, you could use string formatting to duplicate the text with a newline in the middle:

```
print("{0}\n{0}".format(input()))
```

Comment: Ive tried creating a variable as shown in your example above however when I run the program it will only print the variable once despite me asking to print it twice. What would I need to write to get it to print the variable twice on 2 seperate lines?

Comment: @user2633836 The above code *will* print it twice... Have you tried just copying and pasting it?

Comment: I have tried copying and pasting it. It just refuses to print the word out twice. I have tried text = input("Echo") print(text) print(text) but this will only print Echo once using the string formatting how would I write the code? text = input("Echo") print("{0}\n{0}".format(input("Echo"))) is this correct?

Comment: Ive done it thank you both for you assistance really appreciate it

Comment: @user2633836: `input("Echo")` doesn't get `"Echo"` as input, rather it prints `"Echo"` as a prompt and then waits for the user to type in their own text. You may want to read [the docs on the `input` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Answer (score 0):

way complex right?(:D)

```
inp = input("Input something would ya? ")
print(inp)
print(inp)
```